# MS SQL output inserted with insert from select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to combine INSERT FROM SELECT and returning id value of inserted record.

```
INSERT INTO [someDB].[dbo].[OBJ] ( column1, column2, column3 ) 
OUTPUT inserted.ID (SELECT TOP 1 590675, column2, column3 
                    FROM [someDB].[dbo].[OBJ] WHERE ID = 317817)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is a little wrong here.

You want:

```
INSERT INTO [someDB].[dbo].[OBJ] ( column1, column2, column3 )
OUTPUT inserted.ID
SELECT TOP 1
       590675,
       column2,
       column3
FROM [someDB].[dbo].[OBJ] WHERE ID = 317817
ORDER BY ...?; --You have a TOP 1, thus you really need an ORDER BY as well.
```

Comment: Thanks, bracket really should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the new ID after your `INSERT` statement you can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT or @@IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql). For example:

```
INSERT INTO [someDB].[dbo].[OBJ] ( column1, column2, column3 )

SELECT TOP 1
   590675,
   column2,
   column3
FROM [someDB].[dbo].[OBJ] WHERE ID = 317817
ORDER BY ...
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); -- Last identity generated in current session and current scope
SELECT @@IDENTITY; -- Last identity generated in current session across all scopes
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT([someDB].[dbo].[OBJ]) -- Last identity generated for the given table in any session and any scope
```

Because you are inserting just one row, `SCOPE_IDENTIY()` would be the best approach.

Hope it helps.